# URL Domain Name Case Sensitive Using IIS

Tags: php, codeigniter, iis

i have a URL for eg. *localhost/DummyProj*, i have set **IIS Rewrite rule** for **index.php**. when i fire this url for the first time, everything works fine for me, but if i try to **change case** of any letter from "***DummyProj***" to "***dummyProj***" it gives me error "*404 Page Not Found*".

> when i reset the IIS then it takes any case and works fine again.

Below is my webconfig file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>
    <system.webServer>
        <rewrite>
            <rules>
                <rule name="CodeIgniter UrlRewrite" enabled="false">
                    <match url="([_0-9a-z-]+)/([_0-9a-z-]+)" />
                    <action type="Rewrite" url="index.php" />
                    <conditions>
                    </conditions>
                </rule>
                <rule name="Rewrite CI Index">
                    <match url=".*" />
                    <conditions>
                        <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" pattern="css|js|jpg|jpeg|png|gif|ico|htm|html" negate="true" />
                    </conditions>
                    <action type="Rewrite" url="index.php/{R:0}" />
                </rule>
                <rule name="Rewrite to index.php">
                    <match url="index.php|robots.txt|images|test.php" />
                    <action type="None" />
                </rule>
            </rules>
        </rewrite>
    </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

i cannot figure out what is the problem.

my settings are

```
my base_url = ' ' ; index_page = 'index.php'
```

Comment: cant understand you actual problem

Comment: I am getting "404 page Not found" error when i fire the same url second time just by changing case of my domain name character. "http://localhost/DummyProj/loginController?langId=1" works fine but if i change it to "http://localhost/dummyProj/loginController?langId=1" it gives me error. i dont know what and where i am going wrong.

Comment: how your controller is define ??

Comment: in the above link, "loginController" is my controller.  m hoping this is wat u wanted to know.

Comment: Remove empty string from base_url. Best would be to read and follow what is said on lines 4-19 of `APPPATH . 'config/config.php'` file.

Comment: i tried the above but it dint worked for me. as i was trying few things, i got to a point where in if i disable my IIS rewrite Rules it works fine. it takes in any case character for the url, but then if i try to get into any of the links from my main page it gives me again "HTTP Error 404.0 - Not Found" error. but if i try to put "index.php" file name between my folder name and page name, it works fine. ie.http://localhost/bnRMCRZ/loginController?langId=1 Doesnt work for me but http://localhost/bnRMCRZ/index.php/loginController?langId=1 works fine. This all happens when i disable my IIS Rule.

Comment: Not sure if my comment would help but why would you want to change to `localhost/dummyProj/loginController?langId=1` ? Is it because your class name is also `dummyProj`? Aren't all classes supposed to start to caps though? Just asking by the way.

Comment: dummyProj is my main folder, its not a class. hierarchy is c:\www_root\dummyProj\application..i am testing the URL by giving different character case. as a user can basiclly use any case character to get into d website.